# Problema Com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Meu problema é o seguinte quando executo esse código abaixo o echo me retorna 3 valores Repetidos não consegui descobrir o porque vocês poderiam me dar uma força? :D

```
<?php
    try{

        $sql = $pdo->prepare("select * from produtos");
        $sql->execute();
        $resultado = $sql->fetchObject();

        foreach ($resultado as $key) {
            echo $resultado->nome;
            echo $resultado->quantidade;

        }

        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Erro:\n" . $e->getMessage();  
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiseres retornar todos os produtos dessa tabela, terás de usar o `fetchAll` em vez de `fetch` ou `fetchObject` como estás a usar. Sendo que o `fetchAll` retorna uma array contendo todos os valores retornados pela consulta, enquanto os métodos `fetch` e `fetchObject` retornam apenas o primeiro conjunto dessa consulta.

Simplesmente coloca isto:

```
$resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($resultado as $key) {
            echo $key->nome;
            echo $key->quantidade;

        }
```

No lugar disto:

```
$resultado = $sql->fetchObject();
foreach ($resultado as $key) {
            echo $resultado->nome;
            echo $resultado->quantidade;

        }
```

Ou se quiseres manter a tua expressão, coloca o `fetchObject` num loop para retornar os restantes valores.

```
while($retorno = $sql->fetchObject()){
$resultado[] = $retorno;
}
foreach ($resultado as $key) {
        echo $key->nome;
        echo $key->quantidade;
    }
```

Outra coisa é que podes, executar essa consulta usando apenas a função `query` sendo que ela não recebe nenhum parâmetro externo não tem porquê parametrizar a consulta.

Comment: Obrigado bem didático parabéns :D

Comment: Não tens de quê.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está confuso, você está chamando o value de key, para ele ser key, teria que ser `$resultado as $key => $value`, e mesmo assim, o `fetchObject()`, obtém o próximo registro e devolve como um objeto, neste caso você tem que usar `while`:

```
<?php
    try {
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("select * from produtos");
        $sql->execute();

        while ($resultado = $sql->fetchObject()) {
            echo $resultado->nome;
            echo $resultado->quantidade;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Erro:\n" . $e->getMessage();  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar `while` nesse caso

```
while($resultado = $sql->fetchObject()) {
   echo $resultado->nome;
   echo $resultado->quantidade;
}
```